# How to use array for ->whereMonth Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Is it possible to use array as value for function DB:

```
->whereMonth($month);
```

Like this: `->whereMonth([01, 02, 12]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

whereMonth does not support arrays, and the first argument is the column name, not the value.

https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereMonth

You can instead use whereIn with a raw expression:

```
->whereIn(DB::raw('MONTH(column)'), [1,2,3])
```

Comment: I decided to use filter for result collection